What is my problem with this file decryption? (Kotlin/AndroidStudio)
I'm writing an app that let's you connect to a remote computer via ssh.
I want to keep the ssh key protected, so my idea is to encrypt it, then decrypt it inside of the app.
Here's the function I'm using:
    fun decryptFileWithPBKDF2(
        encryptedFile: File,
        decryptedFile: File,
        password: String,
        iterations: Int = 10000,
        keyLength: Int = 256
    ) {
        val saltSize = 8 // OpenSSL salt is 8 bytes
        val ivSize = 16 // AES block size is 16 bytes for CBC mode
        val headerSize = 8 // Salted__ is the first 8 bytes

        FileInputStream(encryptedFile).use { fis ->
            val fileBytes = fis.readBytes()

            // Check if the file is at least large enough to contain the header, salt, and IV
            if (fileBytes.size < headerSize + saltSize + ivSize) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid encrypted file format.")
            }

            // Extract the salt (bytes 8 to 15) and IV (bytes 16 to 31)
            val salt = fileBytes.sliceArray(headerSize until headerSize + saltSize)
            val iv = fileBytes.sliceArray(headerSize + saltSize until headerSize + saltSize + ivSize)

            // Ciphertext starts after "Salted__", salt, and IV (total 32 bytes)
            val cipherText = fileBytes.sliceArray(headerSize + saltSize + ivSize until fileBytes.size)

            // Derive the key using PBKDF2 with the same parameters as OpenSSL
            val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
            val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength)
            val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
            val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(tmp.encoded, "AES")

            // Initialize AES cipher for decryption (AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding)
            val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, IvParameterSpec(iv))

            // Decrypt the file
            val decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherText)

            // Write the decrypted content to the output file
            FileOutputStream(decryptedFile).use { fos ->
                fos.write(decryptedBytes)
            }
        }
    }

Here's the full text in my test.txt:
"This is a serious message! I'm not sure why the decryption ruins this wonderful text :("
And for some reason after the decryption it looks like this:
"s a serious message! I'm not sure why the decryption ruins this wonderful text :("
I encrypted a file like this:
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -salt -in test.txt -out test.enc -k "password" -p

Can you please help me resolve this issue?
I tried using all three big major AI helpers without any success.

The OpenSSL statement produces data that is structured as follows (| means concatenation):
<ASCII encoding of Salted__>|<8 bytes salt>|<ciphertext>

Thereby key and IV are derived from the password and salt using PBKDF2.
You, however, mistakenly assume in your Kotlin code that the IV is also included in the data, but this is not the case. Instead, the IV must be derived alongside the key, e.g. as follows:
...
// Extract the salt (bytes 8 to 15) 
val salt = fileBytes.sliceArray(headerSize until headerSize + saltSize)

// Ciphertext starts after "Salted__", salt (total 16 bytes)
val cipherText = fileBytes.sliceArray(headerSize + saltSize until fileBytes.size)

// Derive the key and IV using PBKDF2 with the same parameters as OpenSSL
val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength + ivSize*8)
val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)

val key = tmp.encoded.sliceArray(0 until keyLength/8)
val iv = tmp.encoded.sliceArray(keyLength/8 until keyLength/8 + ivSize)
val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
...

With this change decryption works.

The garbling of the plaintext can be explained as follows: The original code determines the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext as IV and the rest as ciphertext. Since in CBC mode for a ciphertext block cn the previous ciphertext block cn-1 is applied as IV, this leads to a correct decryption, but without the first block (i.e. the first 16 bytes).

Thank you so much for the solution and the explanation. Works like charm!
